# nav links are hidden - react

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

My nav links are displayed horizontally on desktop/large devices and I have just created a hamburger menu for mobiles. The issue is that I've used react hooks to toggle the links on the hamburger mobile menu when the icon is clicked therefore the links are only displayed if menu is open and so the links are now hidden on larger devices instead of displayed horizontally.
Basically, the nav items are controlled by the mobile hamburger menu even on desktop when they should always be displayed.

How could I toggle the links for the mobile hamburger menu and also keep the links displayed on larger devices? Thanks!

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = ({ history, match }) => {
  const [openNavbar, setOpenNavbar] = useState(false)
  return (
    <ul className="navbar">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img
          className="logo"
          src={logo}
          alt="Logo"
        />
      </a>
<span className="menu-icon" 
onClick={() => setOpenNavbar(!openNavbar)}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon size="lg" icon={faBars} />
      </span>
      {openNavbar && <div className="nav-links">
    {isAuthenticated() && (
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link left-link" to={`/dashboard`}>
            Dashboard
          </Link>
        </li>
      )} 
   
      {isAuthenticated() && (
        <li className="nav-item">
          <WritePostLink />
        </li>
      )}
      
      {!isAuthenticated() && (
        <Fragment>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link className="nav-link" to="/signin">
              Sign In
            </Link>
          </li>
      )}

      {isAuthenticated() && (
        <li className="nav-item">
          <span
            className="nav-link"
            onClick={() =>
              signout(() => {
                history.push("/");
              })
            }>
            Sign Out
          </span>
        </li>
           
      )}
      </div>
          }
    </ul>     
  )}
```

SCSS

```css
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  @include flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  @include flex;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
}

/* hamburger menu - small devices */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-icon {
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    @include flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: right;
    margin-left: 80%;
  }
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .nav-links {
    margin-top: 130px;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: A note, the html is not valid. You can't put `a` or `span` directly under `ul`, you should wrap it with `li`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll change it now. Your answer worked too, thanks! @MoshFeu

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of toggle `.nav-links` div itself, you can toggle a class and hide it using css in mobile only.

Something like

```
{<div className={`nav-links ${openNavbar ? 'open' : ''}`}>...</div>}
```

and in the css

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-links:not(.open) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: amazed by this solution. Simply give an empty class, does let the nav there, otherwise still conditioned by hamburger variable

Comment: Glad you like it :)